# How to change background color of each bar in a for loop for Sorting Visualizer?

Tags: reactjs, loops, sorting, visualizer

I am making an Algorithm sorting visualizer, my problem is that I am not able to figure out how I will change the background colour of each `Bar` while iterating in `for` loop and while adding `console logs` or `set statement of useState` the `for` loop slows down, is there is any way to fix it

And yeah I tried to set the `FirstIndexToCompare` and `SecondIndexToCompare` in the loop but didn't work, while console logging it shows null

Git Repo: https://github.com/the-wrong-guy/Sorting-Algorithm-Visualizer

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, find some hints on how to ask questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Also, please post your code directly here (you can format it with backticks).

Comment: @Clara i tried codesandbox but due to some error i can't replicate the code from the Git repo so share i the Git repo, as you can see above